# How do you set your own intercept in SPSS?

Tags: regression, spss, intercept

I am trying to specify the constant in a regression model using SPSS. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: There are fuller answers at the linked thread. Try reading that. If you still have a question afterwards, come back here & edit your Q to state what you have learned & what you still need to understand, & then we can help you better without simply duplicating material that exists elsewhere & already didn't help you.

Answer (score 6):

(*This is not SPSS-specific.*)  If you want your intercept to be a specific value (say, $17$), subtract that value from all $Y$ values and then fit your model while suppressing the intercept.  Bear in mind that doing this is subject to all the same caveats as forcing your regression line to go through $0$ (cf., [When is it ok to remove the intercept in lm()?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7948/7290), & [When forcing intercept of 0 in linear regression is acceptable/advisable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/102709/7290)).