# I(1) and I(0) variables and cointegration in a trivariate system

Tags: time-series, stationarity, cointegration

I'm a bit confused regarding cointegration and I(1) and I(0) variables. I am testing the residual for cointegration in a regression where the nonstationary variables $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are independent. If $x_1$ is I(1), must $x_2$ and $x_3$ also be I(1) for me to say that they are cointegrated?

Comment: You'll need at least 2 of your 3 variables to be I(1). The third on can be I(0). What framework are you testing in? You can look at this answer to see if it helps you: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130660/test-for-cointegration-between-two-time-series-using-engle-granger-two-step-meth/130762#130762

Comment: The idea with cointegration is that the stochastic trends cancel to produce stationary series. Therefore, in a system with three variables you will need at least 2 variables which are I(1)

Comment: @Plissken, why don't you turn that into an answer.

Comment: @RichardHardy, will do tomorrow.

Comment: @Plissken, tomorrow never came :)