# Test for cointegration in Panel Random effects model

Tags: stata, random-effects-model, cointegration

I am running a panel data regression for 16 countries with 15 annual observations. Due to the fact that EViews does not provide an autocorrelation test for panel data (?), I had to switch for an absolutely unknown STATA. Hausman test (p=0,43) indicated that I should use Random Effects with GLS.

Based on guidelines [here](https://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Panel101.pdf), I tested panel for heteroskedasticity, autocorrelation (HA) which are both present in the panel.

1. To my understanding robust standart errors are fine to estimate approximate coefficients for variables with HA. I used `xtreg rgdppc gerter trade empl, re cluster(id)`. Is this an "okay" method to remove HA? I am new to econometrics.
2. In a post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130660/test-for-cointegration-between-two-time-series-using-engle-granger-two-step-meth), regressions' residual is tested for stationarity. Should I store the Panel RE GLS residual and test it for stationarity? 
   Using Levin-Lin-Chu unit-root test, all series (rgdppc, gerter, trade, empl) showed stationarity (p=0,00), however, with Breitung none of them were stationary. Is this normal?
3. And to the point -  how should I test RE model for cointegration? With aforementioned GLS's residual or I should go instantly for the first difference?