# Box-Cox Transformation for predictor variables in R

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation

I have a data with 5 predictor variables.

The question asks me to predict a box-cox transformation for the independent variables, in R.
I know how box-cox transformation works for response variable, using function boxcox( ) in MASS package.

I searched online but don't seem to get any information in this regard.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "predicting" a Box-Cox transformation?  Would that perhaps be a typo for "calculate" or "estimate the parameter of"?

Comment: @whuber The transformation for each variable. I suppose the lambda value

Comment: Have you looked at the posts on our site?  Check out https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35711, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61217, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60431, among others.