Confusion over BoxCox in R
I'm new to time series forecasting and not coming from a maths degree so please bear with me.
I'm working from an example of how to implement ts forecasting in R and attempting to a) see if I need to apply a transformation to my data, and b) understand how to interpret the BoxCox result from the package forecast package.
I see there are other packages which offer a BoxCox function and these allow you to choose the lambda.
The example I'm following applies the following code:
BoxCox.lambda(data)

The example results in 0.031....which as the documentation states is 'a number indicating the Box-Cox transformation parameter.'
From here, the example I'm following applies a log transformation.
My question relates to the result I get from the BoxCox when using my own time series data. I get a result of 0.59, and upon applying the log transformation there is no visual difference between the before and after transformation. But I can't find information on how to know if I should apply a transformation. I see there are a variety of tests e.g. White test, McLoed Li, stackexchange qhomoscedasticity
but the example I'm following Decomposition vs ETS vs ARIMAseems to draw a conclusion on whether to apply the transformation from the resultant BoxCox figure.
Can someone explain this, is there a cut-off above which the data is more normal and thus not requiring a transformation? How to interpret the BoxCox result of 0.59?

This seems backwards. I might often look at one or more time series on a logarithmic scale if it or they appeared straighter or if variability around any trend or level were more nearly constant. Or occasionally I might use a root scale (implied by power near 0.5) for broadly similar reasons. Whether the marginal distribution is normal -- which is what I guess you're circling around here --- is by comparison somewhere between a little deal and not helpful to any major goal.  The best guide is to plot time series as they arrive and after transformation.

Please consider searching our site, because we already have some good answers posted here.  Wider searches will turn up even more, such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298 on transformations and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60431/ on interpreting Box-Cox parameters produced by automatic procedures.

Ok, thanks @whuber

@NickCox that's what I had read before, thank you. I did wonder was the example I was following jumping the gun and making assumptions etc. Root scales was what I was thinking but then the example confused me
